# When Rema refers to Maharil and it isn't found in Minhagei Maharil, where is it?

Tags: halacha, minhag, minhagim

For example, in [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim, 149:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.149.1)

> שהצבו' לא יצאו מב"ה עד שיצניעו ס"ת ובו ס"א:אין הצבור רשאים לצאת מב"ה עד שיצניעו ס"ת [מיהו אם אינם יוצאים רק יחיד לית לן בה] (ב"י בשם הר"י בחידושי מגילה)  ואם מצניעים הס"ת בבית אחר אם אין לב"ה אלא פתח א' צריכין להתעכב עד שיצא הס"ת וילכו אחריו למקום שמצניעין אותו שם ואם יש לב"ה שני פתחי' יכולים לצאת בפתח אחד קודם שיצא הס"ת בפתח האח' ובלבד שילכו אחר הס"ת וילוהו למקום שמצניעין אותו שם: הגה ובמקומות שמצניעין אותו בהיכל שהוא הארון בב"ה מצוה לכל מי שעוברת לפניו ללותה עד לפני הארון שמכניסין אותו שם **[ד"ע ומהרי"ל]** וכן הגולל ילך אחר הס"ת עד לפני הארון ועומד שם עד שיחזירו הס"ת למקומה [הג"מ פי"ב מה"ת וכן נוהגין במגביה הס"ת כי הוא עיקר הגולל וכמו שנתבאר סי' קמ"ז ס"ד ויש שכתבו שבאים התינוקות לנשק התורה כדי לחנכם ולזרזם במצות וכן נוהגין [אור זרוע]:

Comment: Those references aren't from Rama himself but some later printer/editor

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin) writes that Maharil wrote some responsa as well But more importantly, why do you think there would be a general answer to this question? For all we know a practice of Maharil was reported by a student or friend or a student's student etc. in a work of theirs.

Comment: @DoubleAA can you share some relevant material on when the Rema's text was edited? I would be interested in reading that.

Comment: Besides looking in the Tshuvos Maharil DoubleAA mentioned (btw there are two volumes, with old simanim and newer simanim, making things lots of fun), the first place to look would be the Darcei Moshe on the new edition of the Tur. Check both the regular version on the page and the Darcei Moshe Ha'Aruch in the back. Chances are the source is given better there.

Comment: I looked in Teshuvos as well, I have the set.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer for such a general question.

However, the specific case you refer to is probably sourced to Maharil in error.
Based on the Darcei Moshe Ha'Aruch pictured below, right before the hand, it should probably be מהר'י בן חביב.
It's easy enough to have מהר'י switched to מהרי'ל.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Halakhàh Berurah of HaGaon HaRav David Yosef שליט"א - 134:17:38 refers to Maharil Hilkhot Qeriat HaTorah, Nidfas Mechadash page 438.

Comment: What's written there are the next words in the Ramma regarding the gollel following the seffer Torah back to the aron. The Maharil there doesn't mention everyone that the Torah passes should follow it.